# Question about comment line in java(eclipse)

Tags: java, eclipse, comments

What is the difference between this

```
/**
 * comment goes here (notice the extra '*' in previous line)
 */
```

and this?

```
/*
 * comment goes here (notice the extra '*' is not present in previous line)
 */
```

Because I've noticed that in eclipse these two commenting style have **different colors**.
Firsts one gets **blue color** and second one gets **green color**.

Is there any difference between these two commenting styles?

Comment: One more query, this convetion is general or eclipse specific?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first style is a Javadoc comment, which can be used to generate various documentation formats. Eclipse will use these to generate tooltips and autocomplete documentation for the documented item.

For more detail [see the documentation](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-137868.html).

Answer (score 4):

The first variant is for writing Java-doc comments. The second one is simple multi-line comment in Java.

Answer (score 2):

The comments starting with `/**` are processed by [JavaDoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html#terminology).

Answer (score 2):

`/**` Comments are used to generate Javadoc

`/*` are simple comments

Answer (score 1):

The one that gets colored in blue is compatible with Eclipse's Java documentation generator.

Answer (score 0):

I think that is to difference the ones that are human, from the ones that are automatically generated.

For example: when u use refactor option to implement an interface the comments on top will be green whith the first comments. It is just an eclipse convention

Comment: Nope.  That's not it.  Eclipse has no way of knowing whether a comment was created by hand or automatically.

Comment: Offcourse it doesnt know. But the comments that it generates, like the ones for documentation are always green. That is what i mean, it is just like a convention to add that extra * for those autogenerated.